# How to evaluate two or more element in an set or not in Python

Tags: python

```
s = set([1,2,3])
```

I could do this:

```
1 in s

#=> True
```

I'm wondering without using loop, is there a way to do something like:

```
1,2 in s

#=>True
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use set intersection:

```
>>> s = {1, 2, 3}
>>> t = {1, 2}
>>> s & t == t
True
```

Of course this still has a loop internally.

As spicavigo pointed out you can use `issuperset`, or more concisely you can use `>=` which is equivalent:

```
>>> s >= t
True
```

Again it still has a loop internally, but you probably can't do it any better than that.

See the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/sets.html#set-objects) for more information about set operations.

You can further improve performance if you create your set `{1, 2}` only once one your program starts and store it, rather than recreating it every time you make the test.

Comment: Great answer, that's what I want!

Answer (score 5):

While Mark Byers has given what I feel is an [optimal solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12854635/722121), it's worth noting that a more general solution for other collections, not just sets, can be done with the `all()` builtin:

```
all(item in s for item in {1, 2})
```

Obviously, there is looping internally, but that's going to be true of any solution.

Answer (score 3):

```
a = {1, 2, 3}
if a.issuperset({1, 2}):
    print "Found"
else:
    print "Not Found"
```